# Acumatica/MYOB Advanced API call to get a sales price. Price check

Tags: acumatica, myob

In Acumatica when I add a line to a sales order for instance and select a inventory item the unit price will default to a value based on rules setup in Acumatica via default price or any sales prices setup for the inventory item.  I want to make a call to the API that will return me this price, say if I pass in as parameters the inventoryid, customerid, qty etc.

Does anyone know of a screen or GI that does this, that I can expose to the endpoint?  I dont want to just query the sales prices GI because I then have to recreate the logic Acumatica is using with those results.

I cant seem to find a screen that gives me the result I need.  My other thought was having some sales order I add with the line to get the price and then delete the sales order but thats a bit messy.

Thanks

Comment: you're on to something there with a temporary sales order. You can use a specific order type. Then just do an automation to delete them afterwards. Messy but quick. As the alternative is customisation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Sales Order Quote which was literally designed for that purpose.  Otherwise you can try AR202000

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a customisation from an old course that does it.  Link here if you scroll to the bottom of the comments

https://www.augforums.com/forums/everything-else/pricing-inquiry/